# flutter application with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, github

I downloaded a flutter app from GitHub and it contains Firebase. I cannot run the program because it must be linked first. How do I do this with a program that contains all the codes
please I need help, thanks

Comment: You might want the googleserivces.json file for it to run since gitignore will exclude that file due to privacy concerns. If it's someone's else project you might wanna make a brand new project and add googleservices file for firebase to work or else if it's someone you know you can just ask for that file to get it work with firebase.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: Depends whether you previously worked with firebase or not(experience).**

These are some generic steps for linking existing android app:

1. Go to https://firebase.google.com/ and sign in with your Gmail.
2. Create new project by navigating to console then Add Project(name it anything appropriate) then Continue.
3. On next step you can keep Google Analytics for your Firebase project enabled(I prefer it disabled).
4. Create project.
5. After creation, Select add android app by pressing android logo
6. Register app by adding package name. Your package name is generally the applicationId in your app-level build.gradle file. **(project-directory/android/app/build.gradle)**
7. Download google-services.json and add to app/ directory.
8. Follow further instructions.
9. Continue and then try to run. You may need to enable firebase services implicitly.

P.S: If you face issues afterwards point to the Github repo **if it's public**.